# War File On heroku doesnot run

Tags: java, heroku, war

I tried to deploy the Java 11 war project on heroku. It says `Build Successfully` but the program halts saying `Starting ProtocolHandler`.
[I have attached The Heroku Log Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLov8.png).

I have also created the Procfile needed as

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/tokengenerator.war
```

I have also put the javax.servlet on provided scope

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So, How can I fix this?

Comment: it looks from the logs that the app is started and ready to receive requests. But it looks like the port is not usinng $PORT? do you have it hard coded to 6896? Have you run `heroku open`?

Comment: @codefinger No, I have not hardcoded the PORT. It is being used from $PORT. I don't think the app has started properly as it throws tons of log while running locally. Yes I have tried heroku open but it says 404 Not Found

Comment: Oh a 404 would suggest that the app is running, but you need to add a path. Like `heroku open something`

Comment: @codefinger No It's not working neither my GET or POST request is working. If it's running properly then why it is not showing all the logged information that I get while running locally?